# Azure Policy Storage blobServices/tableServices/queueServices Diagnostic Logging

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-monitoring, azure-policy

Unable to use the available policy since it only checks the storage account and not the services, eg. if I have diag enabled at storage account and don't have it enabled on blobservices it still reports compliant

https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/bbfc60104c2c5b7fa6dd5b784b5d4713ddd55218/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Storage/DataConnectorsStorageAccounts%20_PolicyAssignment.json

So modified the policy to set up diagnostic for blob only with "Mode" set to "ALL" and type: "Microsoft.Storage/StorageAccounts/blobServices"

But in the compliance report for the non compliant resource all the names are returned as Default, and as such the Remediation Template fails. How can we get the storageaccountname to be passed in to the diagnostic deployment

Comment: Hello @user14173614, `Configure diagnostic settings for storage accounts to Log Analytics workspace` Policy can be set for Storage account as well as other services as well . So , whenever a new storage account is created the policy applies if the settings are not enabled then it enables it for every services . You can refer this [Image](https://i.imgur.com/MoPSPaK.png)

Comment: That is right but the use case is different, I have storage account with diag enabled on
Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts

but the diags are not enabled not on one or more of the 
services(blobServices/tableServices/fileServices/queueServices), the policy shows compliant due to the fact that it checks only for 
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"

Comment: Need policy which enable the diagnostic even if any one of them missing, changed mode to all, compliance report is showing 100% correct missing (but the name is default for all the services beneath the storage account so cannot be passed to incremental deployment of the diag)

Comment: policyRule": {
          "if": {
            "anyof": [
              {Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/tableservices/file and so on"

Comment: Can you please add the Screenshot of the parameters in the Policy and the storage account with diag settings to the question as well.. ?? I will try to test the scenario ..

Comment: https://github.com/varshhub/misc/blob/main/storage-all-dine.json

Comment: @user14173614 Please add that policy you just linked to the question, so that future readers can have the context even when the version on github changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate policy for each of the service types (blob, table, etc). This makes it easier to monitor and remediate only the relevant services.

The main change from the BuiltIn policy is that parameter `resourceName` in the deployment needs to be changed to refer to the fullname (`<storageAccountName>/default`) rather than the service name (`default`), like so:

```json
"resourceName": {
  "value": "[field('fullname')]"
}
```

Here is an example for the blob services type. You should be able to modify for the others.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Configure diagnostic settings for blob services",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "Deploys the diagnostic settings for storage account blob services to stream resource logs to a Log Analytics workspace when any storage account blob service which is missing these diagnostic settings is created or updated.",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "Storage"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "logAnalytics": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Log Analytics workspace",
          "description": "Specify the Log Analytics workspace the storage account should be connected to.",
          "strongType": "omsWorkspace",
          "assignPermissions": true
        }
      },
      "diagnosticsSettingNameToUse": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Setting name",
          "description": "Name of the diagnostic settings."
        },
        "defaultValue": "storageAccountsDiagnosticsLogsToWorkspace"
      },
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "DeployIfNotExists",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
      },
      "StorageDelete": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "StorageDelete - Enabled",
          "description": "Whether to stream StorageDelete logs to the Log Analytics workspace - True or False"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "True",
          "False"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "True"
      },
      "StorageWrite": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "StorageWrite - Enabled",
          "description": "Whether to stream StorageWrite logs to the Log Analytics workspace - True or False"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "True",
          "False"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "True"
      },
      "StorageRead": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "StorageRead - Enabled",
          "description": "Whether to stream StorageRead logs to the Log Analytics workspace - True or False"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "True",
          "False"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "True"
      },
      "Transaction": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Transaction - Enabled",
          "description": "Whether to stream Transaction logs to the Log Analytics workspace - True or False"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "True",
          "False"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "True"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices"
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/749f88d5-cbae-40b8-bcfc-e573ddc772fa",
            "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/92aaf0da-9dab-42b6-94a3-d43ce8d16293"
          ],
          "existenceCondition": {
            "allOf": [{
                "anyOf": [{
                    "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics.enabled",
                    "equals": "True"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled",
                    "equals": "True"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/workspaceId",
                "equals": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
              }
            ]
          },
          "deployment": {
            "properties": {
              "mode": "incremental",
              "template": {
                "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "parameters": {
                  "diagnosticsSettingNameToUse": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "resourceName": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "logAnalytics": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "location": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "Transaction": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "StorageRead": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "StorageWrite": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "StorageDelete": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                },
                "variables": {},
                "resources": [{
                  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                  "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
                  "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'),'/', 'Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('diagnosticsSettingNameToUse'))]",
                  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                  "dependsOn": [],
                  "properties": {
                    "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                    "metrics": [{
                      "category": "Transaction",
                      "enabled": "[parameters('Transaction')]",
                      "retentionPolicy": {
                        "days": 0,
                        "enabled": false
                      },
                      "timeGrain": null
                    }],
                    "logs": [{
                        "category": "StorageRead",
                        "enabled": "[parameters('StorageRead')]"
                      },
                      {
                        "category": "StorageWrite",
                        "enabled": "[parameters('StorageWrite')]"
                      },
                      {
                        "category": "StorageDelete",
                        "enabled": "[parameters('StorageDelete')]"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }],
                "outputs": {}
              },
              "parameters": {
                "diagnosticsSettingNameToUse": {
                  "value": "[parameters('diagnosticsSettingNameToUse')]"
                },
                "logAnalytics": {
                  "value": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                },
                "location": {
                  "value": "[field('location')]"
                },
                "resourceName": {
                  "value": "[field('fullname')]"
                },
                "Transaction": {
                  "value": "[parameters('Transaction')]"
                },
                "StorageDelete": {
                  "value": "[parameters('StorageDelete')]"
                },
                "StorageWrite": {
                  "value": "[parameters('StorageWrite')]"
                },
                "StorageRead": {
                  "value": "[parameters('StorageRead')]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sapphiremirage worked and I have separated the policy with each different service types to make it more manageable